# Casting double to int using gcc yields weird results

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion

I have the following program (koko.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    double p = 0.1;
    printf("%lf, %d\n", 1/p, 1/p);
    return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile it using `gcc koko.c -o koko` I get the error:

> koko.c:4:2: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
>     printf("%lf, %d\n", 1/p, (int) 1/p);

If I try to disable Wformat (i.e., `gcc koko.c -Wformat=0 -o koko`), it compiles, but when I run it I get the unexpected output:
`10.000000, -915298312`.

Any thoughts as to why this happens?

[image]

Comment: The error message doesn't match the program. Please post the program you're actually using - the one in your question doesn't have any casts in :-)

Comment: @psmears - see print screen above. ( I had a casting originally, but the problem remains without it).

Comment: copy the code and output text and paste here, not in an image

Answer (score 5):

Operator precedence.

Cast is a higher priority operator than division, meaning it happens first. So this:

```
(int) 1/p
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
((int) 1) / p
```

which results in a `double`.

You want this:

```
 (int)(1/p)
```

And leave those warnings enabled! 99.9999% of the time, the compiler is smater than you!

Comment: ...also, we should warn the OP that even after he fixes this problem, he shouldn't be surprized if `(int)(1/0.1)` does not equal `10`.

Answer (score 3):

The cast operator has [more precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the division. You're doing `((int)1)/p`.

Comment: Higher priority, so it happens first, no?

Comment: I used confusing terminology (where a lower precedence number means that it happens first). The idea is that it happens first, yes.

Comment: When I don't explicitly write `(int)` (see above print screen) the problem remains, do you think it's because of the same reason?

Comment: @RB, printf arguments are not type-checked or coerced and you are responsible to ensure that the parameter types match the first string. When you don't write (int), the result is passed in as a double but printf expects an integer, which causes undefined behaviour.